# jQuery disable multiple input children of a div

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors, children

I want do do something like below from a checkbox,

There's a checkbox on every row, and I'd like to disable all the input fields on a row with the class .room when the checkbox is clicked.

```
function toggleStatus(link) {
    $(link).closest(".room").children(':input').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

also tried

```
function toggleStatus(link) {
    $(link).closest(".room").children('input[type=text]').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: The correct will be attr('disabled', 'disabled'). Not sure however if this is causing the problem.

Comment: @holden: Your wording has me a bit confused. The title says "children of a div" whereas your question says "input fields on a row". Are we talking about stacked divs, or table-rows?

Comment: @holden: Also, does the (div|tr) have the classname "room," or does the input field(s) within the (div|tr)? Perhaps you should just post your HTML.

Comment: Its almost identical to what you posted below, I just modified your js slightly and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has some ambiguities, so the following may not be *exactly* what you're looking for.

Upon click, you should traverse up to the nearest table-row, find all inputs having the classname `.room` and set their disabled-attribute according to the status of the checkbox itself.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").find(":input.room")
    .attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

This assumes a structure similar to that which follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/umimu/edit

Comment: @holden: Lucky guess I suppose :) Glad I could help.